# Set distance as similarity metric for MinHashing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash, set, minhash

I am currently working on document clustering using `MinHashing` technique. However, I am not getting desired results as MinHash is a rough estimation of `Jaccard similarity` and it doesn't suits my requirement.

This is my scenario:

I have a huge set of books and if a single page is given as a query, I need to find the corresponding book from which this page is obtained from. The limitation is, I have features for the entire book and it's impossible to get page-by-page features for the books. In this case, Jaccard similarity is giving poor results if the book is too big. What I really want is the distance between query page and the books (not vice-versa). That is:

Given 2 sets A, B: I want the distance from A to B,

```
dis(A->B) =  (A & B)/A
```

Is there similar distance metric that gives distance from set A to set B. Further, is it still possible to use `MinHashing` algorithm with this kind of similarity metric?

Comment: Can you provide details on your implementation? Which hash functions did you use? How many of them?

Comment: I am using this MinHash implentation with 512 permutations. https://github.com/ekzhu/datasketch

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45320/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

We can estimate your proposed distance function using a similar approach as the MinHash algorithm.

For some hash function `h(x)`, compute the minimal values of `h` over `A` and `B`.  Denote these values `h_min(A)` and `h_min(B)`.  The MinHash algorithm relies on the fact that the probability that `h_min(A) = h_min(B)` is `(A & B) / (A | B)`.  We may observe that the probability that `h_min(A) <= h_min(B)` is `A / (A | B)`.  We can then compute `(A & B) / A` as the ratio of these two probabilities.

Like in the regular MinHash algorithm, we can approximate these probabilities by repeated sampling until the desired variance is achieved.